# Need to Update the data from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, oracle

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['Search']))
  {
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
    $dbname = 'vasuki';
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $Result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, age FROM details WHERE id = '$num'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {
                    $name = $row['name'] ;
        $age = $row['age'];

        echo "<div style='top: 273px;
                margin-left: 60px;
                position: absolute;left: 30px;'>
                <table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th>
                <th> Age </th></tr>
                <tr><td>".$name."</td>
                <td>".$age."</td>
                <td>Edit</td></tr>
                </table></div>";
        }
```

I will explain the concept first :

In first page I insert the person details. and In second page in need to update the details. The above program is for my second page. To update I am searching data using the name and age. If I get the particular person data I need to click Edit and It should go to my 1st page and I need to Update the data.

I completed my html codes. I need to know php code to connect SQL.

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: I don't think that's enough information if you want to update?

Comment: Ok let me explain: In first page I insert the person details. and In second page in need to update the details. The above program is for my second page. To update I am searching data using the name and age. If I get the particular person data I need to click Edit and It should go to my 1st page and I need to Update the data.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: First I need to click edit and IT will be re diracted to my firstpage. Normail html code I tried IT is not helping becoz in program inside echo I wrote HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to redirect to another page, in form you need to add `action="otherpage.php"` and in that other file you need to write something like:

```
if (!empty($_GET['newValue']) {
    mysql_query("update details set name='".$_GET['name']."', age='".$_GET['age']."' WHERE id=".$_GET['id']."");
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

This is approximate approach and there a few things you should change like `mysql` to `mysqli` or PDO (because deprecated) **with** prepared statements and escape all inputs.

Comment: First I need to click edit and IT will be re diracted to my firstpage. Normail html code I tried IT is not helping becoz in program inside echo I wrote HTML

Comment: @Sukki Sorry, I'm having trouble with understanding how to solve you problem. You may need to post nearly entire code (but only parts where the problem is and covering any sensitive data) so that I could find solution that fits you. (or maybe Yagami's solution is fine too?)